# Remove first char in string if found

Tags: c++, string

In C++, if I have string `'aasdfghjkl'` how, for instance, can I check to see if there's an 'a', and if so remove only the first occurrence of it?

I tried `find()` and then
    `templetters.erase('a')` but I think I need to already know the position for that to work.

Comment: `but I think I need to already know the position` -> so what exactly are you having a problem with, such that we can help you specifically?

Comment: well the 'a' would actually be like `firstwords[i][j]`, but Shreevardhan's solution works well.

Comment: I understand. The thing you want to learn about then is __iterators__. They are central to C++.

Comment: Take a C++ reference and look at the string class. It has 105 different kinds of memberfunctions, some of which will surely allow you solve the problem you have. At least it should allow you to ask a more specific question. It's not even "it doesn't work" but "I don't think it works", which is really not helpful at all! Explain what you did, what you saw and what you expected!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
auto it = std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a');
if (it != s.end())
    s.erase(it);
```

**EDIT**: Alternative for `std::string` container only

```
auto pos = s.find('a');
if (pos != std::string::npos)    
    s.erase(pos);
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. What type would it be if not auto?

Comment: @AustinMW It returns an iterator to the container supplied as argument, `std::string`'s iterator here.

Comment: Can you erase the past-the-end iterator that you could get from `find()`? The one-liner looks inconsistent with the preceeding three-liner.

Comment: Oh, and incrementing an iterator by `string::npos` is surely a recipe for desaster! `auto pos = s.find_first_of('a'); if(pos != string::npos) ...` would work, but not without the check.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You can find the "find-erase" pattern often on cppreference (ex: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase), so I assume it's safe

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I think you are right, `string::erase` performs bounds check and throws `std::out_of_bounds` exception.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'll anyway change it to avoid any exceptions thrown. Thanks

Comment: Just for the record: The index-based `string::erase()` overload actually raises an exception, the others cause undefined behaviour, which is a whole different thing! @KABoissonneault, the "find-erase" pattern is used in an example there, which doesn't mean it's generally applicable. In the example, it is also guaranteed that `find()` returns a dereferenceable iterator.